# Rails Select helper in form required True not working

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails 3.2.21 app in which I'm using a `select` helper in a form like so:

```
<%= f.select :phys_option, options_for_select([["N/A", "n/a"], ["No", "no"], ["Yes", "yes"]], :selected => @call.phys_option), :include_blank => true, :required => true, :class => 'select' %>
```

This works with basic functionality for selecting an option, including a blank option, etc.  But what doesn't work is the `:required => true` or the `:class => 'select'`.  I can submit the form even when the selection is blank and my class for the select2 gem `select` doesn't work on this helper method.

Is my syntax wrong or am I missing something?  I can call a model validation to ensure the fields are filled out, but I'd much rather avoid more model validations and try to use the `:required => true` to force a selection.

Any thoughts on why this isn't working?

If you need further detail and/or code, please let me know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= f.select :phys_option, options_for_select(
                            [["N/A", "n/a"], ["No", "no"], ["Yes", "yes"]],
                            :selected => @call.phys_option), 
                           {:include_blank => true},
                           {:required => true, :class => 'select'} %>
```

Comment: Worked!  I figured I needed to pass it as a hash, but was passing all arguments in one hash and it didn't work right.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: How to do it in case of select_tag? its showing argument count error.

Comment: Remember: if `required` is set to `true` then `include_blank` cannot be `false`

Answer (score 0):

**Problem** : Selected item is not displayed in edit

**Solution**

```html
<div class="field form-group">
      <%= form.label :grade %>
      <%= form.select(:grade, options_for_select(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], :selected => form.object.grade), {:include_blank => 'Select Grade'}, class:"form-control", placeholder:"Grade", onchange: "loadRemarksBasedOnGrade()") %>
    </div>
```

**Note**: Use `:selected => form.object.grade` inside options_for_select