# Select a blank option in the static drop-down rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a drop-down menu of a rails form which the user can have the option to choose between 1 to 5. And I want the drop-down to select the blank option at first.

So I tried this:

```
<%= f.select :point1, [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 5]], :include_blank => true %>
```

But it didn't work. Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: So, when the form loads what value do you see getting selected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= f.select :point1, options_for_select([[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 5]]), {:include_blank => true} %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me:

```
<%= f.select :country, countries, {include_blank: true} %>
```

And here's what it could look like if you had HTML arguments to pass through as well:

```
<%= f.select :country, countries, {include_blank: true}, {required: true} %>
```

Note the reason for the **two hashes** is because the first is for rails options and the second is for HTML options

A more extensive example:

```
<%= f.select :country, countries, {include_blank: true, prompt: "United States"}, {required: true, class: "form-control"} %>
```

An [example](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3/form_helpers.html) of the 'two hashes' in rails docs:

```
<% form_for :article, @article, :url => { :action => "create" }, :html => {:class => "nifty_form"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.text_area :body, :size => "60x12" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

And one more example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29695567/5783745)

If you accidentally place html options in with the first hash (rails options), then they simply won't get used, so take care to use both hashes!

Comment: Wow. Passing them in 2 hashes solved it for me as well (Rails 6.0.3). Wouldn't it be a nicer interface if it would wrap that -- I am guessing quite common parameter -- and pass it down to the HTML layer? Just a thought. In the meantime: thanks! That unblocked me.

Comment: @Adeynack for me it was the same, took me a long time to figure out what was going on. Once you know it takes two separate hashes it’s easy enough, but it’s not obvious that it needs arguments in that form